# Send updates from master couchdb to a third party server

Tags: couchdb, pouchdb

I am doing a POC on making an offline first application using CouchDB and PouchDB.

My system will have three components

- master CouchDB
- slave PouchDB(s)
- DB (anyone MySQL, Derby etc).

What I want to achieve is that when the master CouchDB is changed, a CSV is generated of all the changes and sent to the third party server to update the third-party database and vice-versa.

Is there any live implementation I can take reference from? How should I proceed?